# Blender on Mac cannot select anything using trackpad or mouse (3.6.2)

Tags: interface

I downloaded blender for the first time, and started learning the user interface. I looked into preference's key binding and may have adjusted something, but suddenly after that, my trackpad and mouse can no longer click on anything within the App - can't click on objects, can't click on panels, can't even click on the Edit button to open preference again, or the top panel to switch between layouts.

However, keyboard shortcut still worked (e.g. "`" can open the viewport pie selection). Just no left or right or any kind of clicking.

I thought the app may have been corrupted, so I deleted blender and re-downloaded it from the website. However, after the fresh blender opened, it was still exhibiting the same issue.

What setting (bug?) could have caused this? How can it be fixed?

Comment: I know nothing about macs, but it might be an idea to delete the settings folder before doing a new installation in case it's picking up a corrupted setting file that was left behind. The Mac locations are detailed [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#macos).